# mouseMoveEvent is not called

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I need to get mouse movement inside of a widget:

An eventFilter is not possible, since that would be installed on the QApplication. The widget is far down in the type hierarchy. Passing this widget up to the main function where the QApplication object is created would mess up the code.

Therefore I implemented

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
```

in the widget.

None of the events is called.
Even after setting mousetracking to true on both the central widget and the widget where I actually need the event, the functions are not called:

```
centralWidget->setMouseTracking(true);
```

How do you get mouse events in Qt for custom subclass of QWidget ?

**Update**: here is the .h file:

```
class Plot : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
//...

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
```

**Update**:

I tried the eventFilter approach.

in the .h file:

```
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

    bool eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event);
```

in the .cpp :

```
void Plot::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
//...
}
void Plot::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){

}
void Plot::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event){

}

bool Plot::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        QMouseEvent* mev=static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);

        qDebug()<<mev->x();
    }
   return false;
}
```

Then in the constructor of my qWidget:

```
this->installEventFilter(this);
```

The code compiles and runs fine.
Breakpoints at the if statement in the event filter stop the program, the eventFilter method is called. But the if statement is never evaluated to true. Even the simple buttonPress events are not registered.

The overwritten methods for the events are still not called.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.qtforum.org/article/33620/mousemoveevent-is-not-called-even-if-mousetracking-is-set.html) ?

Comment: Can you post the header file of your widget class?

Comment: you could use a normal event filter and check is it a mouse press, release or move event then cast it to a mouse event and then just do whatever you want with it

Comment: @AngryDuck, what is a normal event filter ?

Comment: @MarcoA. , yes that doesn't work

Comment: @Gombat , its quite a long header. I will post the class declaration

Comment: "An eventFilter is not possible, since that would be installed on the QApplication. " mmm, nope. An event filter can be installed on any `QObject`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter. There would be no need to move the object to the application's scope.

Comment: @Ihk: Do you set the parentship during construction?

Comment: @Gombat, no I didn't. The object is a QWidget, so the default constructor passes the parent object on, to the qWidget constructor. But I'm never supplying a parent object. The widgets are positioned via the addWidget method on layouts.

Comment: @Ihk: So you don't provide your own constructors? Constructors are not inherited. You have to pass the given parent to the base class constructor in the initialization list of your constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool someClass::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
         mouseMoveFunction(static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event))
    }
    // Repeat for other mouse events 

   // returning true blocks event returning false doesnt so if you want to block all mouse events except what your handling then return true inside each of your ifs
   return false;
}
```

then install the event filter on what ever you want the filter to be applied to ill assume for this that your in a ui class, which you would do like this (in the constructor)

```
this->installEventFilter(this)
```

EDIT: OP is using QCustomPlot, from previous experience i know this consumes all the events and doesnt pass them back up, so you have to connect to the mouse click (or whatever event you want) signal it emits with the point or event in it

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt. The eventFilter method is called but I can't understand when and why. The if statement never evaluates to true (a breakpoint at the cast never halts).

Comment: it will get called for literally everything this class is doing thats considered an event, if its not getting inside the if statement its because the event isnt ever a MouseMoveEvent. What specifically are you catching the event for because you can set the event filter on that specific ui element or just check the object is what your looking for because checking what the event is.... because this is most certainly how you catch events in Qt my code has this in a lot of places..

Comment: I need the mouseMove event to rotate a 3D object in the widget. Since the mouse movement seems to be tricky, I tried to catch just mouse button presses. Even this doesn't work. The code is in the question, I just edited it in.

Comment: the events I need are button presses and mouse movement. And I only need them on this widget. I installed the event filter on the widget and set the if statement to accept mousebutton presses. But never true

Comment: whats the 3D object in... i assume you have some custom widget or something on your UI that your 3D object is in and thats where your clicking... if so install the event filter on that object `ui->whaterever_the_object_is_called->installEventFilter(this)`

Comment: exactly. The widget contains a qcustomplot and uses qt matrices to create a "3D-impression" with the data plotted in the customplot. Now I would like to rotate the data with the mouse. Therefore I need mouse movement on the qwidget that contains the customplot. This class has the functionality for the 3D drawing and an instance variable with the plotwidget. I need to install the eventfilter on this class. This class is a widget and it is placed in the window.

Comment: ohhh iv used qcustomplot before and im fairly sure it just consumes all the mousevents so youll need to check if there is some signal its emitting with the event or the point that was clicked because im fairly sure it doesnt pass them up

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you very much. Add it to your answer and I will accept it

Comment: No worries, added to answer

Answer (score 3):

I too had need for filtering mouse events in a deep heiarchy, and this answer above didn't quite do it for me. I had to make a small tweek to get things to work.

You need to register the sub-classed widget with the QCoreApplication, but that can easily be done without traversing the hierarchy. In the sub-classed construtor put the following line:

```
QCoreApplication::instance()->installEventFilter(this);
```

Your sub-class will now receive all events and its just a matter of filtering what you need.

---

Full Example

Header File:

```
MouseMoveReaderBox : QScrollArea
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MouseMoveReaderBox(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MouseMoveReaderBox();

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
}
```

Source File:

```
#include "MouseMoveReaderBox"

MouseMoveReaderBox::MouseMoveReaderBox(QWidget *parent = 0)
    : QScrollArea(parent)
{
     QCoreApplicaiton::instance()->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MouseMoveReaderBox::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        // logic here...
        return true; // if you want to intercept
    }
    // Other event type checks here...
    return false; // the signal will be delivered other filters
}
```

Hope this helps because I know I was pulling my hair out!